# What to do when finding duplicates?

Tags: discussion, reputation, exact-duplicates

There are times when several questions seem like they really ask the same question. Yet, sometimes the questions are old and both have their own answers. Is there a technique to merge questions, and what happens to points?

Comment: There is a technique to merge questions, and you can flag them so a moderator can merge them. But I don't know what happens with points, so am posting this as a comment (even though it's really a partial answer). (I'll also remove the `feature-request` tag from your question, since the feature exists.)

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, mods [can merge questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/merge-question-after-finding-it-as-a-duplicate-feature-request) such that the answers all [show up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114557/what-is-the-difference-between-merged-questions-and-closed-exact-duplicate) in the same place. First, one of the questions has to be closed as a duplicate of the other.

The accepted answer on the now-closed question [does not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39862/what-happens-to-both-accepted-answers-during-a-merge) show up as accepted, and the next time that answer's author's reputation is recalculated, the acceptance-bonus [will disappear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50859/losing-my-accepted-answer-points-on-move).

All of the answers that get merged over retain their scores, and, I strongly presume, their effects on their authors' reputation scores.

The closed question, I'm fairly certain, does not accrue additional reputation for its author based on future votes on the retained question. I'm not sure if the merger erases the effect of all previous votes on the closed question, treating it as deleted.